# NSLocalizedString "localizedStringForKey:value:table:"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, localization

```
- (NSString *)localizedStringForKey:(NSString *)key 
                              value:(NSString *)value 
                              table:(NSString *)tableName
```

Doc says about the *tableName* argument in the above method as: The receiver’s string table to search. If tableName is nil or is an empty string, the method attempts to use **the table in Localizable.strings...**

My question is if we create a *Localizable.strings* it creates a string file alone. No tables are created in our project. Where is the table actually? Is it possible to create such string tables manually? I have a need to do that in my project...

And my final question is - What value I have pass as the argument to the *tableName* parameter?

Thank you...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In that context, "table" refers to the file of translations.  So for Localizable.strings, you can get translations from it with NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"foo", @"Localizable", @"comment").  Localizable.strings is the default, however, so you'd typically just use NSLocalizedString(@"foo", @"comment").  If you add a new translation file (say, Settings.strings), then you'd have use the table name to refer to it.

Comment: @jdelStrother don't understand this feature. if i need use several view controllers, so i need to create several *.strings, one for each controller?

Comment: @loldop you could, but you don't have to.  We used to have 1 .string file per xib, but it resulted in a lot of tiny files with a few translations in each.  We've merged them into a handful of files.

Comment: @jdelStrother thanks! i do the same, merging them into similar categories

Answer (score 3):

By table - it just means a key-value pair.

There is more detail in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/StringsFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000005-SW1)

So yes - you have to create these manually - since you are using the NSBundle helper methods for localised strings - you can use `- (NSString *)localizedStringForKey:(NSString *)key value:(NSString *)value table:(NSString *)tableName` and then run `genstrings` to generate the .strings file and the tables.

**Edited to make this clearer**
The Strings table is just a list of key value pairs. If you generate a Localizable.strings file that contains this:

```
/* Text for saying hello */
"HelloText" = "Hello!";
```

Now you can copy this file to another localised .lproj file and change it to the values for the particular language:

```
"HelloText" = "Namaste!";
```

That's all they mean by a table.

Comment: @Abizern: Thank you. I have another question. Where to find the string table for the default "Localizable.strings"?

Comment: There isn't a 'default' version. By 'default' it means the file that will be used if you don't specify one. - run `genstrings` on a source file to generate a string table, and see what it looks like.

Comment: @Abizern: I ran the command `genstrings ./Classes/*.m` on the root directory of my project. It created the "Localizable.strings" file in the directory. It doesn't create any tables. What did I do wrong here?

Comment: @Simon - so what do you see in the `Localizable.strings` files?

Comment: @Abizern: All the strings I defined in my class files are there. But there is no table or something like that.

Comment: @Simon. That is the strings table. You see Key value pairs, right? When you create other localisations, you copy this file into the relevant .lproj folder, and change this file's content to the translated strings.

Comment: @Abizern: What value I have pass as the argument to the tableName parameter?

Comment: `nil` and it will use Localizable.strings; but another name in there, and it will use that.